# With Delphi 12 how to change style defaut and system colors programmatically?

Tags: delphi, themes, vcl-styles, vcl-styles.-utils

Delphi Style editor allows to change individualy the predefined colors in 3 sections "Fonts" "Colors" and "SysColors"
With themes enabled, I would like to do the same but programmatically by code.

For example trying to set by code

`clHighlight := clRed`

doesn't work

Is there a way to do this ? Since the style editor can do it I was full of hope ... but did not find a clue

Comment: If you have styles enabled then you can only switch to different style. You can't programmatically change individual properties defined within style itself. So come style editor allows changing of these? That is because Style editor prepares special resource file that is then compiled into final executable. So your application is limited only in reading from the specific style.

Comment: `clHighlight` is not a real color, it is just a flag that tells the RTL to ask the OS for the actual color when needed. So you can't redirect it to a different color value.

Comment: Hi Remy, Style colors (and system colors) can be changed in style designer, and styles can be applied at runtime, so I believe Styles do not ask directly the OS color, there is an in between translation. For exemple I have found this code in VCL.Styles : < function TCustomStyle.DoGetSystemColor(Color: TColor): TColor;
begin
  Result := TseStyle(FSource).SysColors[Color];
  if Result = TColor(clNone) then
    Result := Color;
end;> I just can't figure out how to access this SysColor array

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm allowed to answer my own question :
I have created the following helper :

```
unit StyleColor;

interface

uses Vcl.Themes, Vcl.Styles, Vcl.StyleAPI;

   TStyleHelper = class helper for TCustomStyle
   public
      procedure DoSetSystemColor(SysColor: TColor; Color: TColor);
   end;

implementation

{ TStyleHelper }

procedure TStyleHelper.DoSetSystemColor(SysColor: TColor; Color: TColor);
begin
   TseStyle(FSource).SysColors[SysColor] := Color;
end;

end.



and when I call it like this : (with themes enabled)

if TStyleManager.ActiveStyle is TCustomStyle then
begin
   TCustomStyle(TStyleManager.ActiveStyle).DoSetSystemColor(clHighLight, clRed);
end;
```

it Works !!!!  all clHighLight items are Colored in Red !